# google Storage Transfer API get stuck at the calculating step

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

When I try to launch a transfer from Amazon S3 to Google GCS using the google API from the console, my transfer keep stuck at the "calculating" step. I have been using this API a lot for four months and it is the first time I get this kind of behaviour. Maybe be this problem is linked with the last API version deployment.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Transfer is stuck at calculating step...

Comment: yep same here. i'm using the TSV means of transferring my files. started out using a TSV with all the files just tried it with a single file. how long could THAT take to calculate?? a long time it would seem.